# Send notification to status bar

Tags: cordova

I try to buid a phonegap app and I want to send notification to status bar of the phone(like facebook app when you receive a notification).
I build my app on `build.phonegap.com` because I'm newbie.
Can anyone send me a tutorial how I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you there is currently a means by which you can send a notification to the status bar outside of a native app atm?

Comment: I want something similar to facebook app(when you receive a notification)

Comment: Maybe, Pushover could help facilitate push notifications for your web app?

https://pushover.net/